# How to use accordion using telerik control

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, c#-4.0, telerik-mvc

I want to use JQuery accordion with Telerik control for my mvc3 project. When i am calling accordion function. It is throwing me an error accordion is not a function. Tried many things, but couldn't find a solution. Looking for a solution to integrate JQuery accordion with Telerik Controls or can anyone suggest best solutions like accordion to integrate in my project.

Comment: When i was trying to use the accordion function it is throwing an error accordion is not a function.

Comment: Does accordion work without telerik controls

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use Telerik Panel Bar instead?

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/panelbar